# AWS Pricing API not yielding prices for the given search criteria

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pagination, boto3

I am using AWS boto3 pricing api to get the prices of instances.

But I am not getting the results for the combination (us west 2, r3.2x large, Linux, No pre software installed, tenancy =shared)

Here is my code:

```
pricing = boto3.client('pricing', region_name='us-east-1')
hourlyTermCode = 'JRTCKXETXF'
rateCode = '6YS6EN2CT7'
token = ''
while True:
    paginator = pricing.get_paginator('get_products')
    pages = paginator.paginate(
        ServiceCode='AmazonEC2',
        Filters=[
            {'Type': 'TERM_MATCH', 'Field': 'operatingSystem', 'Value': 'Linux'},
            {'Type': 'TERM_MATCH', 'Field': 'location', 'Value': 'US West (Oregon)'}

        ],

        PaginationConfig={
            'StartingToken':token
        }
    )

    for response in pages:
        for price in response['PriceList']:
            resp = json.loads(price)
            product = resp['product']  # ['attributes']['']
            sku = product['sku']

            if product['productFamily'] == 'Compute Instance':
                if str(product['attributes']['instanceType']) == str(amazon_instance_type) :
                    if str(product['attributes']['operatingSystem']) == 'Linux':
                        if str(product['attributes']['preInstalledSw']) == 'NA':
                            if str(product['attributes']['tenancy']) == 'Shared':
                                sku_key = resp['terms']['OnDemand'].get(sku)
                                if sku_key:
                                    price = sku_key[sku + '.' + hourlyTermCode + '.' + rateCode]['pricePerUnit']['USD']
                                    print 'here 7'
                                    print price

        try:
            token = response['NextToken']
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

Comment: I would suggest that you adopt the strategy of getting the code to return *something* first.  Make it much less restrictive.  Add some "else" branches to print the values that did *not* match, for inspection.  Print out the entire response or price and examine it visually.  It may be that you're using an hourly term code and/or rate code that aren't applicable to us-west-2.

Comment: Hi @Michael-sqlbot: Yeah tried that and for the matching key that I found in the offer file, the api somehow gives, Key Error for that matching sku.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
import json
import boto3

client = boto3.client('pricing', region_name='us-east-1')

response = client.get_products(
    ServiceCode='AmazonEC2',
    Filters=[
        {'Type': 'TERM_MATCH', 'Field': 'operatingSystem', 'Value': 'Linux'},
        {'Type': 'TERM_MATCH', 'Field': 'location', 'Value': 'US West (Oregon)'},
        {'Type': 'TERM_MATCH', 'Field': 'instanceType', 'Value': 'r3.2xlarge'},
        {'Type': 'TERM_MATCH', 'Field': 'tenancy', 'Value': 'Shared'},
        {'Type': 'TERM_MATCH', 'Field': 'preInstalledSw', 'Value': 'NA'}
    ]
)

for pricelist_json in response['PriceList']:
    pricelist = json.loads(pricelist_json)
    product = pricelist['product']

    if product['productFamily'] == 'Compute Instance':
        print pricelist['terms']['OnDemand'].values()[0]['priceDimensions'].values()[0][u'pricePerUnit']['USD']
```

It is based on the output of:

```
{u'FormatVersion': u'aws_v1', u'PriceList': [u'{
            "product": {
                "productFamily": "Compute Instance",
                "attributes": {
                    "enhancedNetworkingSupported": "Yes",
                    "memory": "61 GiB",
                    "vcpu": "8",
                    "capacitystatus": "Used",
                    "locationType": "AWS Region",
                    "storage": "1 x 160 SSD",
                    "instanceFamily": "Memory optimized",
                    "operatingSystem": "Linux",
                    "physicalProcessor": "Intel Xeon E5-2670 v2 (Ivy Bridge)",
                    "clockSpeed": "2.5 GHz",
                    "ecu": "26",
                    "networkPerformance": "High",
                    "servicename": "Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud",
                    "instanceType": "r3.2xlarge",
                    "tenancy": "Shared",
                    "usagetype": "USW2-BoxUsage:r3.2xlarge",
                    "normalizationSizeFactor": "16",
                    "processorFeatures": "Intel AVX; Intel Turbo",
                    "servicecode": "AmazonEC2",
                    "licenseModel": "No License required",
                    "currentGeneration": "No",
                    "preInstalledSw": "NA",
                    "location": "US West (Oregon)",
                    "processorArchitecture": "64-bit",
                    "operation": "RunInstances"
                },
                "sku": "GMTWE5CTY4FEUYDN"
            },
            "serviceCode": "AmazonEC2",
            "terms": {
                "OnDemand": {
                    "GMTWE5CTY4FEUYDN.JRTCKXETXF": {
                        "priceDimensions": {
                            "GMTWE5CTY4FEUYDN.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7": {
                                "unit": "Hrs",
                                "endRange": "Inf",
                                "description": "$0.665 per On Demand Linux r3.2xlarge Instance Hour",
                                "appliesTo": [],
                                "rateCode": "GMTWE5CTY4FEUYDN.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7",
                                "beginRange": "0",
                                "pricePerUnit": {
                                    "USD": "0.6650000000"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "sku": "GMTWE5CTY4FEUYDN",
                        "effectiveDate": "2018-07-01T00:00:00Z",
                        "offerTermCode": "JRTCKXETXF",
                        "termAttributes": {}
                    }
                },
                ...
            },
            "version": "20180726190848",
            "publicationDate": "2018-07-26T19:08:48Z"
        }'
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This solution is perfect, removes the dependency on sku or offer code or rate code. However, why don't we require pagination? What's the use case for that and why doesn't it apply in this case?

Comment: The additional filters meant that very few (one?) results were returned. Therefore, pagination was not necessary. If you have less filters, more results will be returned, so pagination may be required.